# How to restart / refresh contents of activity on notification click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, push-notification, android-pendingintent

I am trying to refresh the contents of an activity on click of a notification. I can navigate to the activity when I am in some other activity and I click on the notification. What I am trying to achieve is,
I am in Activity A which is displaying some content. I get a new notification, I click on it Activity A should either be relaunched or the content in the activity should be refreshed with respect to what I am passing in the PendingIntent of the Notification.

What all I have done,

1. Tried setting `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` and `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`
2. Tried setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
               Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in the intent I am passing along with the pending intent.
3. Checked the data in `onNewIntent()` its doesn't get refreshed. I get the same data which I have passed in the old intent.
4. Passed a unique `requestCode` along with the PendingIntent as well, still the same.

Any Other suggestions?

Comment: Try `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. Check [this definition link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

Comment: Used that as well. no luck.

Comment: Please post the code you use to put the data in the Notification and also the code you use in `onNewIntent()` to get the data from the `Intent`

Comment: @iZBasit Please post your answer if you have any solution. Because I am also stuck with same problem.

Comment: @Srinivasan I started using the Greenrobot's event bus in the project so it solved this problem for me automatically.

Comment: @iZBasit thank you for the immediate response. I will try to use the event bus.

Comment: guys we are facing this issue, please post it as an answer if event bus is working, also pls let us know event bus solved your problem

Comment: @pappu_kutty yes event bus will solve your problem. I am using Greenrobot's eventbus.

Comment: @iZBasit thats really cool

Answer (score 6):

If you use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, this should recreate the activity if it was in the stack, or start a new activity if it wasn't in the stack. If you don't want the activity to be recreated (if it is already in the stack), you can use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.

Comment: Your answer should be the right answer. It is actually enough to use only `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to recreate the activity if it was already in the stack. This flag's docs states: "If it (the target activity) has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default (was changed to "standard")) and you have not set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in the same intent, then it (activity) will be finished and re-created;". I tested it and it is indeed true! :) Any special reason why I should have also `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` if I'm not interested in creating additional task?

Comment: Technically you should have `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` if you are launching the `Activity` from a non-activity `Context`. In the case described, OP is creating a `Notification` and therefore the `Activity` will be launched from a non-activity `Context`. Android is a bit forgiving about this, but if you look in the logcat you should see a warning if you don't specify this flag in a `Notification`. Using this flag in this way doesn't actually create a new task if there is already a task containing this app. It actually launches the `Activity` into the existing task (if there is one).

Answer (score 4):

As **aldoran** said, use LocalBroadcastManager. In your Activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(FILTER_STRING));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("receiver", "Got message");
  }
};
```

And then in GSM Broadcast put your data in intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FILTER_STRING);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Why in the world should/would I use broadcast receiver and send a broadcast I don't understand!

Comment: Sorry, I inattentively read the question. What is launchMode of Activity A? Try to set singleTop in Manifest.

Comment: It is SingleInstance as of now. Have tried the same with SingleTop. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
           Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
           notificationIntent.putExtra(CommonConstants.EXTRA_NOTE_ID, note.get_id());
           notificationIntent.setAction(CommonConstants.NOTE_NOTIFICATION_REMINDER);

           notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
           PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, note.get_id(), notificationIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
           NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name)).setContentText(note.getMessage());
           mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
           mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
           mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
           NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
           mNotificationManager.notify(note.get_id(), mBuilder.build());
```

most important you have to call

```
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, note.get_id(), notificationIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

or

PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

Answer (score -1):

You could also use `LocalBroadcastManager` or write your own `BroadcastReceiver` and then send `Broadcast` from your `Notification`

Comment: Excuse me? What are you saying?
I am already getting a broadcast from GCM and am handling it in a Service and showing the message in a notification. What I want is to handle the activity cycle on notification click!